# Do not show diskspace and db for Spring Boot Actuator /health endpoint

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator

I am running Spring Boot v1.5.2.RELEASE.

When I do `curl localhost:8080/health` i get:

```
{
    "status": "UP",
    "test": {
        "status": "UNKNOWN",
        "hello": "test123"
    },
    "diskSpace": {
        "status": "UP",
        "total": 999234207744,
        "free": 806942392320,
        "threshold": 10485760
    },
    "db": {
        "status": "UP",
        "database": "MySQL",
        "hello": 1
    }
}
```

Here is my code below for TestHealthIndicator.java:

```
import org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.AbstractHealthIndicator;
import org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.Health.Builder;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class TestHealthIndicator extends AbstractHealthIndicator {

    @Override
    protected void doHealthCheck(Builder builder) throws Exception {
        builder.withDetail("hello", "test123");
    }
}
```

I also have this in my `pom.xml`:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

**Question**: How do I get `/health` to return something like below without the db and diskspace information?

```
{
    "status": "UP",
    "test": {
        "status": "UNKNOWN",
        "hello": "test123"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to the [docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/production-ready-endpoints.html#_auto_configured_healthindicators) you can disable all of custom `HealthIndicator` beans with the following property:

```
management.health.defaults.enabled=false
```